# For responsive images with different aspect ratios, what's a good way to minimize Cumulative Layout Shift?

Tags: performance, pagespeed, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights, web-performance

If you have a `<picture>` element with image sources at different aspect ratios at different breakpoints, what is the best way to minimize CLS by using aspect-ratio and media queries in CSS?

Answer (score 14):

For `<picture>`, you should be [fine](https://web.dev/optimize-cls/) as long as each `<source>` image has the same aspect-ratio in your responsive image snippet:

```html
<img width="1000" height="1000"
       src="puppy-1000.jpg"
    srcset="puppy-1000.jpg 1000w,
            puppy-2000.jpg 2000w,
            puppy-3000.jpg 3000w"
           alt="Puppy with balloons"/>
```

For `<picture>` where each `<source>` has a different aspect-ratio, browsers are awaiting [standardization](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/4968) of width/height being recommended for each `<source>` for the art-direction use-case:

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/600x279" media="(max-width: 599px)" width="600" height="279">
  <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x300" media="(max-width: 991px)" width="1500" height="300">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x300" width="1500" height="300">
</picture>
```

In the meantime, you can provide `height` through [padding-top CSS hacks](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/), with different media-queries per `<picture>` breakpoint.

Comment: width/height in <source> is working now in Chrome 90 (the linked github issue was closed)

Answer (score 9):

The source element supporting [dimension attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content-other.html#dimension-attributes) is [now](https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/5894) part of the HTML standard — https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-source-element

The standardisation matches [the example implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62722095/4587822) [@addyo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3151817/addyo) already provided.

For the art-direction use-case of a `<picture>`, where each `<source>` has a different aspect-ratio, each `<source>` can provide its own `width` and `height` value.

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/600x279" media="(max-width: 599px)" width="600" height="279">
  <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x300" media="(max-width: 991px)" width="1500" height="300">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x300" width="1500" height="300">
</picture>
```

Implementation for browser support is [underway](https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/5894#issuecomment-785306587) and should be trackable in [caniuse soon](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/5791).