# Is it possible to reduce the amount of sources in this picture element?

Tags: html, image, pagespeed, lighthouse, web-performance

I’m writing a Laravel Blade component that will print a `<picture/>` element with different sources. Based on the layout and on the availability of images there can be different configurations, but in any case I think that the resulting markup is very long, so I’m asking if there can be a shorter way of doing the same thing.

This is the starting image:

```html
<img src="img_home_desk.jpg" width="1340" height="777"/>
```

For this image I also have `avif` and `webp` versions, so I have to add a surrounding picture element with the two alternative sources:

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="img_home_desk.avif" type="image/avif">
  <source srcset="img_home_desk.webp" type="image/webp">
  <img src="img_home_desk.jpg" width="1340" height="777"/>
</picture>
```

Now I want a smaller image to be shown for non retina displays, so I add the 1x version:

```html
<picture>
  <source
    srcset="img_home_desk.avif 2x, img_home_desk_670.avif"
    type="image/avif"
  >
  <source
    srcset="img_home_desk.webp 2x, img_home_desk_670.webp"
    type="image/webp"
  >
  <img src="img_home_desk.jpg" width="1340" height="777"/>
</picture>
```

Now if I want a different image for the mobile viewport, I have to add two more sources. For the small images I don’t have the retina versions, but those images have a different ratio, so I will specify the width and height in the sources (see: [For responsive images with different aspect ratios, what's a good way to minimize Cumulative Layout Shift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62722094/for-responsive-images-with-different-aspect-ratios-whats-a-good-way-to-minimiz))

```html
<picture>
  <source
    srcset="img_home_desk.avif 2x, img_home_desk_670.avif"
    media="(min-width: 992px)"
    type="image/avif"
  >
  <source
    srcset="img_home_desk.webp 2x, img_home_desk_670.webp"
    media="(min-width: 992px)"
    type="image/webp"
  >
  <source
    srcset="img_home_desk_750.avif"
    media="(max-width: 991px)"
    type="image/avif"
    width="750"
    height="440"
  >
  <source
     srcset="img_home_desk_750.webp"
     media="(max-width: 991px)"
     type="image/webp"
     width="750"
     height="440"
    >
   <img src="img_home_desk.jpg" width="1340" height="777"/>
</picture>
```

At this point I thought I was done, but if I remember correctly Lighthouse was still complaining that the images were too large for some viewports. So I added two intermediate images for both the mobile and the desktop viewports.

Please note that for every new image size I have two formats, so now we have 4 new source elements:

```html
<picture>
  <source
    srcset="img_home_desk.avif 2x, img_home_desk_670.avif"
    media="(min-width: 1200px)"
    type="image/avif"
  >
  <source
    srcset="img_home_desk.webp 2x, img_home_desk_670.webp"
    media="(min-width: 1200px)"
    type="image/webp"
  >
  <source
    srcset="img_home_desk_1140.avif 2x, img_home_desk_570.avif"
    media="(min-width: 992px)"
    type="image/avif"
  >
  <source
    srcset="img_home_desk_1140.webp 2x, img_home_desk_570.webp"
    media="(min-width: 992px)"
    type="image/webp"
  >
  <source
    srcset="img_home_desk_750.avif"
    media="(min-width: 413px)"
    type="image/avif"
    width="750"
    height="440"
  >
  <source
    srcset="img_home_desk_750.webp"
    media="(min-width: 413px)"
    type="image/webp"
    width="750"
    height="440"
  >
  <source
    srcset="img_home_desk_600.avif"
    media="(max-width: 412px)"
    type="image/avif"
    width="750"
    height="440"
  >
  <source
    srcset="img_home_desk_600.webp"
    media="(max-width: 412px)"
    type="image/webp"
    width="750"
    height="440"
  >
  <img src="img_home_desk.jpg" width="1340" height="777"/>
</picture>
```

Please note that I have simplified the srcs of the images to make my point clearer, but in reality the images are generated by a CMS (Contentful) by passing some parameters (for example `img_home_desk.jpg?fm=webp&w=764`), so in order to make this work we don’t need to actually create all those variations: in the end when the browser computes the correct image to download there will only be one request to the server.

So my question is: do you think that there is a shorter way of expressing this? I’ve seen that it’s possible to list different sources in the `srcset` property, but they can’t be mixed with the 2x density descriptors (as explained here: https://www.debugbear.com/blog/responsive-images) so maybe it’s not possible to create a shorter syntax for my use case (where there can be 2x versions for every source), but I’d like to have some suggestions on how this syntax can be improved.

Comment: _"but in any case I think that the resulting markup is very long"_ - okay, and who exactly _cares_ ...? That's a couple hundred extra bytes at most. So in relation to the overall "size" of web sites these days, hardly relevant from the data size perspective at least.

Comment: You could of course only refer _one_ image format in the HTML, instead of all three of them - and then use URL rewriting on the server side, to serve the most appropriate format, based on the `Accept` header the client has send.